# in React componentDidMount() { is not working but i get no errors

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

export class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(".dropdown-submenu a.test").on("click", function(e) {
      $(this)
        .next("ul")
        .toggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

render() {...
 }
}

export default App;
```

Now im not getting any errors but my componentDiDMount is just not working and i don't get why. Im new to react so maybe there is a glaring issue that im not seeing. Any help/insight would be awesome.

Comment: React and jquery are fundamentally at odds with each-other. If you can reframe your question without the jquery, you'll likely get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The componentDidMount function is probably working but as @AKX says, using jQuery and React together is a bad idea. Instead, use React/JSX's built in APIs, such as `state` to do your onClick event. Something like this:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  state = {
    showDropdown: false
  }

  toggleDropdown(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ showDropdown: !this.state.showDropdown })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleDropdown}>Show dropdown</span>
        {this.state.showDropdown && <ul>...</dropdown>}
      </div>
  }
}
```

What's happening here? First we declare the component, as you've done. Second, we initialise a state variable (used to be done inside a `constructor` but [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) make it unecessary). This is initially set to `false`, so the dropdown will only show when the button is clicked. To show it when the component renders, change to `true`.

Next we declare our function which handles the click event. This prevents the default action (i.e navigate to /#) and then toggles the value of `showDropdown` to the opposite of what it currently is.

We then set up the render; passing `toggleDropdown` to the `onClick` event. This is JSX so may look a little different to how you're familiar with event handlers and such. Finally, we only show the dropdown element if `this.state.showDropdown` is true.

So the `componentDidMount` part of the code is actually unecessary - if you wanted to try it out you could run `this.setState({ showDropdown: true })` in it to see if the dropdown shows when the component mounts/renders. But only do this to test, as something this simple could be done in the `state` variable where we initially set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

You *must not* mix and match jQuery with React unless you know exactly what you're doing.

There's absolutely no guarantee that the DOM nodes you may or may not see in `componentDidMount()` will retain their event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

#### Jquery and React

React handles events directly and uses a virtual DOM, in theory using React should mean you simply don't need to use jQuery as well. Changing the browser DOM outside your React app means React is potentially no longer handling state, events and UI rendering. [Source](https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-mix-jquery-and-react-cit77t20z02j5fq536wlyiwtk)

Generally, I would try to avoid using Jquery in combination with React if possible.

#### Solution

I recommend taking the HTML element corresponding to the class '**.dropdown-submenu a.test**' and moving it into this component or a separate one with JSX being rendered.

If you are unsure, you can read about how to do that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Once you have this new component, you can render your JSX and then use react's onClick event handler to achieve what you want. You can read about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Finally, to target your unordered List element (ul) you can use react refs to do that, [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

All of this information can be found in the react documentation.